# HVAC thermostat current

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat

What is the typical current (in mA) carried by the 24v thermostat HVAC wire bundle in a typical low voltage application?  I'm using 18/7 wire.

Comment: You might find some good information here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11403/ethernet-cable-instead-of-thermostat-wire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HVAC transformers are commonly rated 24 volts, 40 volt-amperes (VA).  So they should be capable of providing about 1.6 amperes.

`40 VA ÷ 24 V = 1.666666 A`

However, the amount of current flowing, depends on what load is connected. If the load is only drawing 5 mA, then only 5 mA will flow on the wire.